# get information about users erros with an android app

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to know if is possible to receive the information of an error, when a a user have it. so it can be fixed in further versions. this, because, I don't have all the devices to test my application on. I never published an app on the android market before, so I don't now to much of how it works. Also. I would like to know what happens if the app is shared via bluetooth, is this going to increase my downloads number or not?

thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: ACRA is probably the best crash reporting solution see http://code.google.com/p/acra/

Second: You can share your app via apk or html/qr code. By using html/qr code the receiver has to download the app (from market). If you share an apk than its not related to the market

Comment: thanks, for the info, also the ACRA seems to be the solution I was looking for. pitifully, if the users share the app via bluetooth it will not be taken in to account for my counter.